How can I filter a ListTile elements in ListView.Builder?
Let's say I have a list like this:
final list = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "c"]

And I use
ListView.Builder(
                itemCount: list.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                builder: (context, index){
                   return ListTile(
                       title: Text(list.index),
                       onTap:(){}
          )
      }
   )

Is there a way I can filter the list so that it displays only the objects that only contain "a"?

Please see [ask]. Your title should be a clear, specific question without tags.

list literally has "a" three times.  did you mean to have examples like "ax" "apple" "aardvark"?

Just use the List's .where method to filter out elements that only contain the string "a":
final listWithOnlyA = myCurrentList.where((element) => element == "a").toList();

You can also use .contains:
  final listWithOnlyA = list.where((element) => element.contains("a")).toList(); 

Using your example:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

final list = ["a", "a", "b", "a", "c"];

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final listWithOnlyA = list.where((element) => element == "a").toList();
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Material App',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Material App Bar'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: listWithOnlyA.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(listWithOnlyA[index]),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



